# Laravel Import excel with column name variable

Tags: laravel-10

Good morning everyone, I'm using Laravel 10 and I import Excel files without problems, but now I have a problem that I don't know how to solve. Sometimes the file I import changes the name of a column and I would like to avoid problems when loading, it is possible to assign a variable of the column name in order to import the file whether it is called Workflow_status_Id or workflow_status

```
 public function model(array $row)
    {
        $request = request()->all();

        return new Ticket([
            'time_stamp' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['time_stamp']),
            'status' =>  $row['id_status_workflow'],
```

Comment: solved by putting a 'status' => $row['status_workflow'] ?? $row['id_status_workflow'],